# Which R object does return this JSON structure?

Tags: json, r, rjson

After `R` to `JSON` conversion, this should be the output:

```
{
    "alpha": [100,120,140,150,160],
    "beta": [0.6, 1, 1.5, 2],
    "gamma": [
        [
            0.018429082998491217,
            -0.1973461380810494,
            0.6373366343601572,
            0.1533790888325718,
            0.014712015654254968
        ],
        [
            0.012075950866910893,
            -0.14585424179257,
            0.6591589092698342,
            0.2571689477155383,
            0.010925520086793088
        ],
        [
            0.0159193430322232,
            -0.146917626129837,
            0.4710901890006199,
            0.15728143658310957,
            0.012566273548505473
        ],
        [
            0.017317835334994967,
            -0.1549043092753231,
            0.4882454969264185,
            0.1300951912298256,
            0.013437976685378085
        ]
    ]
}
```

This describes a matrix: `alpha` and `beta` are arrays which index the matrix depicted below by columns.

`rjson::toJSON()` function from `rjson` takes `vector` or `list`. However, it doesn't split an `R` matrix (with named rows and columns) in arrays; instead, it generates an array of row values and then names each column by its column name.

I cannot really figure out which `R` data structure allows producing such a file format.

Could you show me the `R` code that uses `rjson::toJSON()` function and generates that output?

Comment: A list of vectors?

Comment: The `jsonlite` package will format matrices that way: `jsonlite::toJSON(list(alpha=1:5, beta=1:5, gamma=matrix(1:15, nrow=3)))`

Comment: It's all just nested lists: `rjson::toJSON(list(alpha = 1:5, beta = 6:10, gamma = replicate(4, rnorm(5), simplify = FALSE)))`